# Build flow and recovery php application

Tags: php

I have application in windows that when is new event in the system it is called to PHP script to run the flow;
the flow means to create a row in DB row on the server, upload an image and update the DB, and another few server call.
also when there is an error or problem from the server the local machine needs to keep the same row in the local DB and also keep the current position so when the recover script will see that need to be recovered he will run only from that part and not from start.

for now, I have a function that calls to other function like:

***pseudo code ****

```
function run(){
   $this->createDBRow(),
   $this->getimagesdata()
   $this->uploadImage()
   $this->updateServerDB()
}
```

I think to create a switch case like:

```
switch ("ENUM_ACTION"){
   case:"create_db_row" 
             $this->createDBRow(),
       $this->getimagesdata()
       $this->uploadImage()
       $this->updateServerDB()
   case:"get_images" 
       $this->getimagesdata()
       $this->uploadImage()
       $this->updateServerDB()
   case: "upload_images"
        $this->uploadImage()
       $this->updateServerDB()

}
```

How can I do that, something like queue of event and to know exactly from where to start if I want to recover event that has been failed

also when I want to recover I need to check the part in the local db and take the server row for example

but how also I prevent duplicate code in the switch case

maybe I need a queue manager instead, the switch is not a good solution?
thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but by looking to the code I think you didn't understand how the [`switch` control statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) works. The `case` statements are not alternatives, they are entry points in the block of code. On the `'create_db_row'` case, all the listed code is executed (i.e. `$this->updateServerDB()` runs `3` times.)

Comment: Why not have a global variable that tells you how far the process has gone? When you need to recover, the flag will tell you where to start from?

Comment: Also, the listed code doesn't run at all because the `switch` expression is a literal string (constant value) that doesn't match any of the `case` expressions (also constant values).

Comment: @Mawg .  I am opened to new suggestion it is just what I think 
maybe I need queue manager?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not add `break`s to your switch case it will act like a funnel based on your entry point.

```
switch ($enum_action){ //<-- this should be a variable that contains yours case name
    case "create_db_row":
        $this->createDBRow();
        // Break missing on purpose to allow further execution
    case "get_images":
        $this->getimagesdata();
        // Break missing on purpose to allow further execution
    case "upload_images":
        $this->uploadImage();
        $this->updateServerDB();
        break;
    default:
        throw new \Exception("Unknown case");
}
```

Comment: As a good practice, it's recommended to add a comment instead of the `break` statement, that explains that the `break` statement is missing on purpose. Upvoted the answer nevertheless.

Comment: @axiac yes, you are correct, added comments so hope this makes you happy ;)